# Partially disable or simulate a weaker GPU in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu

I'm using an AMD A10-7850K and I'm benchmarking a program I wrote. To get a rough idea of the scaling performance, I'm "simulating" a CPU with less cores by launching 2 threads instead of 3 (for example). Is there something similar I could do for the GPU?

I'm only launching the kernel once, so I was thinking that if there's a way to check the execution unit ID a thread is running on (or something similar) then I could just not run that particular thread on the GPU.

Answer (score 3):

You have <s>three</s> two ways of doing this, taking into account that you only want to run the kernel once. Considering, in an abstract way, that your kernels currently process one work unit:

1) The first way is to reduce the global work size, and add an outward loop to the kernel so that each kernel instance processes more than one work unit. For example if your global work size is currently 4096 (i.e. there are 4096 work units to process), reduce it to 512 and make each kernel instance process 8 work units (512 * 8 = 4096) using an outward for loop. Using, for example, a local work size of 256, this means you're only going to use two work groups, and thus two GPU compute units (512 / 256 = 2).

2) Another way is to test your kernel while there is another very long kernel running in the background. However this probably won't give you very consistent results.

<s>3) Finally, you can also partition your device into multiple sub-devices, and then run the kernel on one these sub-devices. A sub-device can have just one compute unit.</s>

EDIT: As was brought to my attention in the comments box by @Cicada, AMD GPUs don't support device fission as of May 2015.

Comment: Number 3: are you aware of any GPU that supports device fission? :)

Comment: No 4: take 20$ and get a 5 years old graphic card from eBay.

Comment: @Cicada, I think most AMD GPUs support device fission. I have access to a lowly HD 6320 (integrated in the E-450 APU) and to a high-end(ish) HD 7970 (same as R9 280X), and both support device fission. The person who asked the question has a A10-7850K APU, which is way more advanced than the E-450 APU containing the HD 6320, so I guess it also supports device fission. I also have access to several NVidia boards, and none support device fission, even with the latest OpenCL 1.2 drivers.

Comment: Really? I have a 6750 and last I checked it didn't support device fission. Good to know, anyway!

Comment: @Cicada, I tested device fission in the GPUs I mentioned, and in fact it doesn't work. I was mislead by the AMD GPUs reporting a valid CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_MAX_SUB_DEVICES value, contrary to NVidia GPUs which returns 1. A closer look reveals that CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_PROPERTIES is empty, so as you said, AMD GPUs don't yet support device fission. However, the first two answers are still valid. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Running different number of work groups if you are running many.
2. Using less number of work items in the workgroup. AMD max is 256 work items per work group.
3. <del>Create sub-device (clCreateSubDevices). I.e. if a GPU contains 16 processing units you can partition it into 2 sub-devices each containing 8 computing units and use one of them.</del> As @Cicada and @faken pointed out device fission doesn't really work in AMD GPU's. I've also tested it on my HD 7570 and is not working.